# Multiple inline css less compiling with Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, less

I have a folder of some .html files, each of them has a style tag with inline css

```
<style type="text/less">
```

I'm wondering how write a Grunt task that takes all these style tags, less compiles all them and write the result inside a file.
Any advice?

Comment: Obviously you need to find a tool (or write your own) that first can extract those styles form html text. So your Q is really both "too broad ("any advice?" hmm, mm...) and "offtopic" ("searching for a tool"). What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well I was hoping someone had written something similar and give me an idea... I know how to compile less files and write the result in a new file but I don't know how take all style tags inside my folder.